# Выборка всех строк со строго определённым значением

Tags: mysql, база-данных

Допустим есть две таблицы:
users — таблица с пользователями:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
orders — таблица с заказами
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Нужно выбрать всех пользователей из таблицы users, у которых ВСЕ записи в таблице orders имеют status = 1.
Как я не пробовал не получается сформировать такой запрос.

Comment: join или IN к тому вопросу по дублю сами допишите

Comment: @Mike, мне кажется, вы ошиблись. Как-то совсем сложно получается.

Comment: @Mrak Да, почти ошибся, not exists из вашего ответа возможно проще, но он сработает и в том случае если не будет ни одной записи в orders. т.е. он не гарантирует наличия записи со статусом 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Все заказы имеют статус 1" равносильно "Нет ни одного заказа со статусом не 1"

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE NOT EXISTS 
(SELECT id FROM orders WHERE orders.user_id = users.id AND status != 1)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
select distinct
       t1.user_name,
       t1.user_surname,
       t2.id  as 'order_id'
  from users  as t1
  join orders as t2 on t2.user_id = t1.id
                   and t2.status = 1
```

Comment: Этот запрос покажет пользователей, у которых есть хоть один заказ со статусом 1. А нужно наоборот - чтобы все были со статусом 1.